# How to change the order of integration to get equivalent integrals?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Consider 
$$ I_{1} = \int_{0}^{\infty} b(a)  e^{\epsilon a} \int_{a}^{\infty} \epsilon e^{(\gamma-\epsilon) z} \int_{z}^{\infty} \tilde{b}(x) \rho e^{-D(x)-qx- \gamma x} dx dz da   $$

$$ I_{2} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \tilde{b}(\tilde{a}) \rho e^{-D(\tilde{a})-q \tilde{a} - \gamma \tilde{a}} \int_{0}^{\tilde{a}} \epsilon e^{(\gamma - \epsilon)z} \int_{0}^{z} b(y) e^{\epsilon y} dy dz d \tilde{a} 
 $$
$I_{1}$ will be equal to $I_{2}$ after changing the order of integration. I started with $I_{1}$ and then I tried to change the order of integration in last two integrals but that really does not help me. I am very curious to know if there is any smart technique to handle this problem.

Comment: It looks like it's not only about changing the order of integration because the bounds are being changed also. And $a$ is somehow changed to $\bar{a}$. You will need to explain us what the variables and functions mean.

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: Your edited note is false. If it were true, each of the $I_1$ limits of integration would have $0$ on the bottom and each of the $I_2$ limits of integration would have $\infty$ on top. Neither is true. When you integrate in higher dimensions, you are not integrating over intervals. You are integration over regions - here, subsets of $\Bbb R^3$. *One* of the conditions for $I_1$ and $I_2$ to be equal is that these regions are the same. You need to figure out what those two sets are, and determine if they are the same.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, I just meant to say that these $a$ and $\tilde{a}$ are just dummy variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change the dummy variables in each so that they play the same roles. In this case, I'd change $y = a$ in $I_1$ and $x = \tilde a$ in $I_2$:

$$I_1 = \int_0^\infty b(y)e^{\epsilon a} \int_y^\infty \epsilon e^{(\gamma-\epsilon) z} \int_z^\infty \tilde b(x) \rho e^{-D(x)-qx- \gamma x}\,dxdzdy\\
I_2 = \int_0^\infty \tilde{b}(x) \rho e^{-D(x)-qx - \gamma x} \int_0^x \epsilon e^{(\gamma - \epsilon)z} \int_{0}^{z} b(y) e^{\epsilon y}\,dydzdx$$

If we bring all the integrands inside, we see that they are the same function in both $I_1$ and $I_2$.

In $I_1$, we have $0 \le y$ for the first integral, $y \le z$ from the second integral, and $z \le x$ from the third integral. So the region of integration is $\{(x,y,z)\mid 0 \le y \le z \le x\}$.

In $I_2$, we have $0 \le x, y, z$ from the three integrals, $z \le x$ from the second integral, and $y \le z$ from the third integral. So once again, the region of integration is $\{(x,y,z)\mid 0 \le y \le z \le x\}$.

So both integrals are of the same function over the same region. If the volume integral over the region converges, then these two iterated integrals must also converge to the same value (as would any of the other four iterated integrals over that region).

In general, the volume integral need not converge even if both iterated integrals converge (and if the volume integral does not converge, there is no guarantee the iterated integrals will converge to the same value). However in this case the integrand is the product of separate functions for each variable. And if all three of these 1D functions converge when integrated from $0$ to $\infty$, the volume integral can be shown to converge as well.

Comment: Wow! you made this complex problem very easy.

Comment: Well, I did handwave the justification for exchanging the order of integration in the final paragraph. I could have gone into detail about the theorem allowing that exchange, and actually demonstrating that a product $f(x)g(y)h(z)$ of integrable functions of the individual variables will satisfy that theorem.